# Collect data into variable in rails form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a rails application in which I have a form to add student information. The form has text fields for name, age, address etc. Normally when you press the submit button, this info would be submitted to the server and you can create a new student when the page refreshes.

I do not want this. I want that when the submit button is pressed, it would hold these data in a variable(or any other means) and then I can continue adding next student info. I can continue this multiple times. After adding n students, I would press the Finish button and the data of all n students should be submitted to the server. Is this possible?

Comment: The standard answer for this question is to use nested attributes.  This is explained quite well in [Railscast 196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised).

Comment: Maybe [#217 Multistep Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms)?

Comment: Or using javascript... http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind this approach? Because I see several possible alternative approaches, and it depends a bit on the requirements which route you should take.

Answer (score 0):

```
i am adding an example here...

a.first name and last name with dynamically add  n number of address details and phone number 
b.have a separate table for name, address and phone.
c.one to many relation
d name can have number of address and phone.(have name id as foreign key in address and phone table)

ex:
first name = tom, last name = jerry, address:xx1, phone:yy1,address:xx2, phone:yy2.

store it like

first name = tom, last name = jerry, address:xx1, phone:yy1
first name = tom, last name = jerry, address:xx2, phone:yy2



sample erb file

    <%= form_tag(controller: "contacts", action: "create", method: "post", )  do %>


    <blockquote>
    <%= label_tag :first_name %>
    <%= text_field_tag :first_name, params[:first_name] %>

    <%= label_tag :last_name %>
    <%= text_field_tag :last_name, params[:last_name] %>
    </blockquote>

      <blockquote>
    <h3>Adress Details </h3>
    <div id="skillSet1">
      <%= render 'address' %>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="addNewTag1">Add Additional Address Details</a>

    <div class="hide" id="new_skills_form1">
      <%= render partial: "address", locals: {skill: false} %>
    </div>
      </blockquote>

    <blockquote>
    <h3>Phone Number </h3>
    <div id="skillSet">
      <%= render 'phone' %>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="addNewTag">Add Additional Phone Details</a>

    <div class="hide" id="new_skills_form">
      <%= render partial: "phone", locals: {skill: false} %>
    </div>

    </blockquote>
    <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Back', :action => :index %></div>
<% end %>

javascript

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addNewTag").click(function(){
        $("#skillSet").append($("#new_skills_form").html());
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addNewTag1").click(function(){
        $("#skillSet1").append($("#new_skills_form1").html());
    });
});
```